# Should the "close" link be changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Nothing is closed any longer. Things are put on hold.

Shouldn't the "close" link be changed to "hold"?

Is this even important? I know if I were a new user and saw votes to hold rather than votes to close, I'd feel a bit better.

Comment: Definitely an overdue tweak, not that I can vote to close anymore anyway. :)

Comment: You can't @Dominic? Why? Live site rep requirements?

Comment: Yep I fell from grace. :) I was so happy when I could see all that other stuff (like a secret agent :P). I'll get there again eventually! Only 3k for close votes anyway.

Comment: Well I'd give you 5k if I could :)

Comment: Email it to me: repcheater@cheatforrep.com, no one will know! ;) Thanks for that though, it's a nice compliment. :)

Comment: @Dominic I know it's not quite the same, but you can still flag things as "it should be closed for another reason...", then it'll get placed in the review queue